# List the first files from a list of files

Tags: r

I have this code to read multiple csv files.

```
path <- "C:/Users/cfees/My Box Files/Fitness/"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="myfile_.+\\.csv")
```

I want to load in a for look every csv into every iteration.

I try a simple way to read the first csv file from the list with this but I receive the error.

```
df <- read.csv(path+files[1])
Error in path + files[1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What can I do?

Comment: That is not how string concatenation works in `r`. See the [first result](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/rw1001/library/base/html/paste.html) from a Google search.

Comment: You can also avoid the problem entirely with the `full.names` parameter as documented in [`list.files`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html)

Comment: @ruaridhw unfortunately I tried paste but here are the results: > `paste(path,file[1], , sep = "")
Error in file[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: @ruaridhw I prefer to not use the full names as I uses files as variables in my code

Comment: `file` is a function. `files[1]` is the first element of the vector you defined. There is also no need for the third comma.

Comment: Pozmanski, I suggest using `full.names`, and then using `basename(path)` to create your variable names. (This assumes of course that you *never* have a same filename in two different directories.)

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to use `file.path` to concatenate paths, it will deal with path ending with `/` or not, more robust:

```
df <- read.csv(file.path(path,files[1]))
```